# Parsing an array using Decodable

Tags: ios, json, swift4, decodable

Here is my JSON which I am trying to parse and want to understand the container concept.

```
 {
"results": [
{
  "type": "TEST",
  "date": 1518633000000,
  "slots": [
    {
      "startDatetime": 1518665400000,
      "endDatetime": 1518667200000,
    },
    {
      "startDatetime": 1518667200000,
      "endDatetime": 1518669000000,
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

This is what I am trying using my code. I have also made a struct for `slots` confirming decodable protocol. I am getting this error while parsing `Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead`. Please give me solution using overriding of Decodable protocol.
Error occurs at this line, when decoder try to decode results.

```
struct Slots: Codable
{
var startDateTime: UInt64?
var endDateTime: UInt64?
}

struct Results:Codable {
var type:String?
var date:UInt64?
var slots:[Slots]?

private enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey
{
    case type
    case date
    case slots
}

private enum ResultsKey: String, CodingKey
{
    case results
}

public init(from decoder:Decoder) throws
{
   let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ResultsKey.self)
    let resultsValues = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .results)
    type = try resultsValues.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
    date = try resultsValues.decode(UInt64.self, forKey: .date)
    slots = try resultsValues.decode([Slots].self, forKey: .slots)
}
}

 if let data = response.data {
            // init the decoder here
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()

            // Error occurs here
            let results = try! decoder.decode(Results.self, from: data)
        }
```

Comment: At what line does the error occur? Also, what is a Slots? Provide everything needs for someone else to reproduce.

Comment: omitted some keys for better readability and added the error line, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the classic mistake. You forgot the root (the outermost) object, the dictionary with key `results`.

You don't need any coding keys nor an initializer and you can decode the timestamps directly to `Date` by adding one line

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let results : [Result]
}

struct Result : Decodable {
    let type : String
    let date : Date
    let slots: [Slot]
}

struct Slot : Decodable {
    let startDatetime, endDatetime : Date
}
```

---

Assuming `data` is the JSON string in `Data` format

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .millisecondsSince1970
    let result = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch { print(error) }
```

**And do not declare every property schematically and carelessly as optional**.

Comment: I am following this tutorial and trying to understand the container concept, for my case result is the key for the container. If I really want to use coding keys, how I'll do that?  Your one line can clear my confusion.

Comment: https://medium.com/@phillfarrugia/encoding-and-decoding-json-with-swift-4-3832bf21c9a8

Comment: I have to declare only that property optional, which could be absent from the response, right?

Comment: The error message is clear. The value for `results` is an array so actually you need the `nestedUnkeyedContainer`. But this is not a good example to learn / do that. And yes, declare **only** optionals if the key can be missing.